# focus on empty field when submit button is clicked in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

here is my html code

```
<section class="main">
<form class="form-2" name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="check()">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" >
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" >
    <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail id" >
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile Number"  >
    <input type="password" id="pass1" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" >
    <input type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" placeholder="Re-type Password" >
    <button type="submit" name="submit" ></button>                      
</form>
</section>
```

my javascript :

```
function check () {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var mail = document.getElementById('mail').value;
    var numb = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass1').value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2').value;

    if((name == "") && (mail == "") && (numb == "") && (pass1 == "") && (pass2 == ""))
    {
        alert("Make sure that you've entered all the details :(");
        document.getElementById('name').focus();
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("form1").action = "register_2step_1.php";
    }
```

Am trying this - When the submit button is clicked it checks for empty fields. If empty fields are available it must focus the name textbox.
The above code actualy focuses the field but the page is immediately getting loaded and the values are getting reset. I don't want the page to load. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need to intercept and block the submit method by returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in HTML

```
<form class="form-2" name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="DoSubmit();">
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="0" />
<input type="text" name="message" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="0" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="name" value="0" />
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""placeholder="Your Name" >
 <input type="hidden" name="username" value="0" />
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value=""placeholder="Username" >
 <input type="hidden" name="mail" value="0" />
<input type="text" id="mail" name="mail"value="" placeholder="E-mail id" >
 <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="0" />
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"value="" placeholder="Mobile Number"  >
 <input type="hidden" name="pass1" value="0" />
<input type="password" id="pass1" name="pass1"value="" placeholder="Password" >
 <input type="hidden" name="pass2" value="0" />
<input type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2"value="" placeholder="Re-type Password" >
</form>
```

Then in JS

```
function DoSubmit(){
    if((name == "") && (mail == "") && (numb == "") && (pass1 == "") && (pass2 == ""))
    {
            alert("Make sure that you've entered all the details :(");
            document.getElementById('name').focus();
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
            document.getElementById("form1").action = "register_2step_1.php";
         document.form1.message.value = '1';
         document.form1.submit.value = '1';
         document.form1.name.value = '1';
         document.form1.username.value = '1';
         document.form1.mail.value = '1';
         document.form1.phone.value = '1';
         document.form1.pass1.value = '1';
         document.form1.pass2.value = '1';
          return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope! This didn't work. When i give any one of the field, the action gets triggered.

Comment: I meant like this ... check now... little debugs might needed look into it

Answer (score 2):

Return false from the check method

```
if((name == "") && (mail == "") && (numb == "") && (pass1 == "") && (pass2 == ""))
    {
        alert("Make sure that you've entered all the details :(");
        document.getElementById('name').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("form1").action = "register_2step_1.php";
      return true;
    }
```

Update :

```
<form onsubmit="return check()">
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it doesn't seems to work. Still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Change `onsubmit="check()"` to `onsubmit("check();return false")`

Comment: Are you suggesting an inline event handler? Shouldn't it be `onclick="..."`?

Comment: My mistake, don't change onsubmit as it fires when form is submitting. onclick does not work when eg. somebody clicks `enter` key.